# Poppler: How to extract fillable form text?

Tags: qt, poppler

**The problem:**

I am using poppler in embedded systems (printers) that use Qt4 or Qt5, to view and print pdf documents.
I need to be able to print **fillable forms** on **pre-printed supply**. 
That requires being able to print **only the part of the forms that is user-filled**, not the directions. And they have to fit onto the pre-printed form.
I can grab the `Poppler::FormField` for a page -

```
QList<Poppler::FormField *> fields = page->formFields();
```

but these fields contain the directions as well as the fillable section.
In addition, I don't know if there is a way to create a page and place the fields on it - I have not found a way.

**What I tried:**

1. Create a `QGraphicsScene` and add text items containing the form field text. 
   Then render and print the `QGraphicsScene`.
   **The problem:** The font sizes, spacing, alignment ... did not match what is on the screen and did not fit correctly on the form.
2. Create a `QImage` containing black rectangles corresponding to the form field rectangles, then composing the rendered page using `QPainter::CompositionMode_SourceIn` 
   **The problem:** While everything is aligned correctly, I get the directions (possibly clipped), which is not allowed because they would be printed on top of the pre-printed ones, likely off and different color.

**What I need:**

- I would like to get the fields without the directions,
- I need a way to place them on a page exactly as they were on the original page.
- Maybe a different way to perform this, that I have not tried ?

Hopefully something that works with both Qt4.8 and 5.x poppler versions, since I have printer models that require different Qt versions. 
OS: Linux Ubuntu (different versions) 
Qt using c++ (different versions)

Comment: Why did you deleted your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70524036/qt-click-on-an-app-around-a-modal-dialog/. How did you solve your issue? If it may be useful to others, please consider creating an answer yourself.

Comment: @m7913d I did not solve it, the solution I need is more specific. I really need an event to bring the app in front, because the app is embedded into another using QWinhost. My options, as I explained in question, were either to not use modals, but filter their events to pretend they are, or override QWidget's event, unsure if that is enough and unsure of side effects. I deleted because while my purpose is bringing the app in front, my specific need is to receive app level events (so I can signal the container to come in front).